# Get column data from sql database and store in label/string

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm intent to retrieve only column data from SQLdatabase and store in a string or label as a holder.

**CASE:**
select all the email address from the database "tblUser" WHERE apple = 1 and store in a "emaillist" string holder,then attach with mail.to.add(emaillist);

**Note:**
ExecuteScalar only allow me to retrieve 1st row of my database. Consequently only first row of email address is able to retrieve. (E.g.,user@user.com)

**Expect Result:**
emaillist which consist of "user@user.com,testing.gmail.com,admin@admin.com" and so on.

**My code:**

```
     String status = "1";
    SqlConnection conn100 = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated                     Security=true;database=WebsiteDatabase");
    conn100.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd100 = conn100.CreateCommand();
    cmd100.CommandText = "select emailaddress from tblUser where apple= '" + status + "'";
        string selected100 = cmd100.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        String emailcontent = "";
        emailcontent = "" + selected1 + "- Highlight: " + selected2;
        String emaillist = "" + selected100;
        //Create a new MailMessage in order to send email
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //The recipient of this email
        mail.To.Add("recipient@gmail.com" + emaillist);

        //The sender of this email
        mail.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");

        //The subject of this email
        mail.Subject = "Latest Product";

        //The email's content
        string body = "New Product added! " + emailcontent;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Create new smtpClient and use smtp services
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        //SMTP host (Gmail)
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        //SMTP port
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        //Sender Email and password
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "password");

        //Enable SSL in order to have secure transmission
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        //Send the email
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: When executing a query that returns more than one record you should use a SqlDataReader and then loop over the rows returned.

Comment: Your intent isn't very clear (to me at least) here, are you returning multiple email addresses - and you maybe want to `group by` them to prevent duplicates? Also, `ExecuteScalar` should only be used to return a single value - if you're selecting a row, you will only get the first column of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing a query that returns more than one record you should use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) and then loop over the rows returned

```
....
conn100.Open();
SqlCommand cmd100 = conn100.CreateCommand();
cmd100.CommandText = "select emailaddress from tblUser where apple= @status";
cmd100.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd100.ExecuteReader();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(dr.Read())
{
   sb.AppendFormat("{0},", dr[0].ToString());
}
```

I have changed your code also to remove the string concatenation in the sql text command, I have also used a StringBuilder to build up your destination list because it is more efficient when you have many strings to concatenate together.

```
....
// Now the StringBuilder contains all of your To Address separated by a comma as required 
// Clip away the last comma
sb.Length = sb.Length - 1;
mail.To.Add(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use execute reader. It will help you.
MSDN Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx

```
string str="";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   str+=dr[0].ToString()+",";
}
```

and remove the last comma at the end.

Or you can take benefit of List as follow

```
  var userEmail = new List<string>();

  while (lobjDtReader.Read())
  {
       userEmail .Add(lobjDtReader[0].ToString());
  }

  var Emails = string.Join(",", userEmail );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String status = "1";
SqlConnection conn100 = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated                     Security=true;database=WebsiteDatabase");
conn100.Open();
SqlCommand cmd100 = conn100.CreateCommand();
cmd100.CommandText = "select emailaddress from tblUser where apple= '" + status + "'";
    SqlDataReader dr= cmd100.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
string selected100= dr("emailaddress").ToString();
}

    String emailcontent = "";
    emailcontent = "" + selected1 + "- Highlight: " + selected2;
    String emaillist = "" + selected100;
    //Create a new MailMessage in order to send email
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    //The recipient of this email
    mail.To.Add("recipient@gmail.com" + emaillist);
......................
```